# How to use keys to be as indicator?

Tags: php, html, arrays

As I am exploring arrays and how to use it

I encounter this unusual array.

I am trying to achieve this ouput using the array I have posted below.

**How can I get this done?**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>DOGS</th>
      <th>CATS</th>
      <th>BIRDS</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $dogs;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $cats;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $birds;?></td>
   </tr>
</table>

Array
(
    [cats] => Array
        (
            [0] => persian
            [1] => ragdoll
            [2] => siberian
            [3] => savannah
        )

    [dogs] => Array
        (
            [0] => husky
            [1] => bulldog
            [2] => beagle
            [3] => labrador
        )

    [birds] => Array
        (
            [0] => parrot
            [1] => owl
            [2] => eagle
            [3] => love birds
        )
)
```

**This is the output I really need to get:**

```
DOGS       CATS       BIRDS
husky      persian    parrot
bulldog    ragdoll    owl
beagle     siberian   eagle
labrador   savannah   love birds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop them first, you cannot outright echo arrays:

```
$animals = array(
    'dogs' => array('husky', 'bulldog', 'beagle', 'labrador'),
    'cats' => array('persian', 'ragdoll', 'siberian', 'savannah'),
    'birds' => array('parrot', 'owl', 'eagle', 'love birds'),
);

?>

<table cellpadding="10">
<tr><th>DOGS</th><th>CATS</th><th>BIRDS</th></tr>
<?php
$types = array_keys($animals);
for($i = 0; $i < count($animals['cats']); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($types as $type) {
        echo '<td>' . $animals[$type][$i] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uqcLk6)

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 yeah i just thought this way, get the keys first so that you can line them up in an echo properly

Comment: oh yah you just think thats way, i was trying to solve this. as i am not good with array, so i was busting my self, than i see some body posted a answer. So i check your sample output link many times, and i was thinking How on earth this working then i understood. Oh yah this man is clever. And you are saying just think that. cool man.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 basically, the first for loop determines how many rows it will loop, the second loop (foreach) basically is the one responsible for the the columns, since you have to line them up (dogs, cats, birds, from the array keys) ,

Comment: Thanks for the response, and i did understand it after reading many times on the link given by you(English is not my frist language hope i dont confuse you). I know it might be a big ask. Can you suggest any book or tutorial. particularly in playing with array. if you dont reply its ok.  At the moment i am checking some of the answer given by you and learning a good deal. I must say you are  genius.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 to be quite honest if i wasn't participating here on SO,  i still would have trouble solving this. answering here on SO is just like learning itself, by answering questions here you get to hone your knowledge. it doesn't matter if you got the most points or even not being accepted. the important thing is you learn constantly.

Comment: Thanks for the response and yah you are right. Have a nice day.